# Returning Wordpress Custom Field Values

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to echo the key of a custom field (value, such as a URL set while editing a post) back into the document. Here's the overall code:

```
        <div id="feature" class="clearfix">

                     <?php  
                        $feature_post = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=1');
                        foreach( $feature_post as $post ) : 
                    ?>
                        <div class="feature_post" style='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature', true); ?>'>
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    <?php 
                        endforeach; 
                    ?>

            </div>
```

Specifically, this is the line of code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature', true); ?>
```

That doesn't print anything - any ideas?

The custom field on the post is already 'feature', there's no CSS issues or Javascript, it's just not returning the values.

Comment: If you get it to echo only the $post->ID does that return anything. The syntax is correct.

Stupid Question, but you want the contents of feature to be in the Stlye section? Have you looked at the source behind the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `global $post;` before you call `get_posts()` function and don't use $post naming in foreach() loop, then see if it works or not!  If failed simply use this code instead:

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query('cat=3&showposts=1');
    if($loop->have_posts()): 
        while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
?>
            <div class="feature_post" style="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature', true); ?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that `category=3` works, but use `cat=3` in your `get_posts` statement.

Also need `setup_postdata($post);` after your foreach statement.

Sepehr Lajevardi's solution should also work nicely ;)